# Imageview is picked up as circleimageview and doesn't display selected image

Tags: java, android

I've been struggling for days now with displaying a selected picture on an imageview, all I need is that when a user selects or take a picture, the image should be displayed in my imageview inside my fragment, for now nothing happens and for some reason android studio picks up my imageview as a circleimageview, not sure if that could be the issue though, I've gone through Imageview problems in here and I couldn't find any relation to my problem cos I wanna avoid asking something that's already been answered, if it has please forgive me but I really need the help with this I am stuck, thank you in advance hey -).

Here's my fragment xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/enquirefragment"
    tools:context="com.infamuspips.cess.enquire_Fragment">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:id="@+id/app_icon"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Community "
        android:id="@+id/app_title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Engagement Surveilance "
        android:id="@+id/app_title1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_title"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please Log your question! "
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_title1"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/app_title1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/app_title1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click to use image for questioning"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout="@+id/imageView"
        android:id="@+id/questioning"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/app_title1" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_above="@+id/logIn"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/enquire"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/questioning"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint = "module name"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_title1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/app_title1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app_title1" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/enquire"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/autocomplete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my methods within my Fragment class

```
     public class enquire_Fragment extends Fragment {

         @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        RelativeLayout enquire = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enquire_, container, false);
        return Myview;
    }

       public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Run Background Activity
        Module = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        GetModules getmodules = new GetModules();
        getmodules.execute();
        //Find ChildObjects
        up = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        down = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        enquire = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.enquire);
        que = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.questioning);
        imageView = (ImageView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        //Set attributes
        up.setEnabled(false);
        down.setEnabled(false);
        que.setClickable(true);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        Module.requestFocus();
        Module.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
        enquire.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);

        //Call operations
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
        que.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
    }


     private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    //File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    //@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException el) {
                        el.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                //Log.w(getActivity()"path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath+"");
                ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            }
        }
    }
```

Here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.infamuspips.cess">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".registration"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reg_name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reg_securityquestions"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reg_id"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reg_cellnumber"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reg_email"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".reg_password"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Maindrawer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maindrawer"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here are my gradle file-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.infamuspips.cess"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say Android Studio picks up your ImageView as a CircleImageView? I'm unclear on that part of the question. The xml has both an ImageView and a CircleImageView. I can't see where you've actually declared the variable "imageView", is there any chance you may have declared it "CircleImageView imageView" by accident? I see you're new to SO, if you could format your question to break out the code sections (separate sections for your xml, fragment class, etc) it would be much easier for people to read the question and be more inclined to take a look & answer.

Comment: In fragment's `onCreateView ()`, you have `RelativeLayout enquire = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enquire_, container, false);
        return Myview;` . Where comes `Myview` from ?

Comment: Hi, excuse me if i'm not more detailed, imageView = (ImageView)  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView); declared on onActivityCreated() and "View Myview" is declared above onCreateView hence i'm returning myview, what I mean by imageview getting picked as circleimageview is that when I debug my code, for instance for my button I get "button: AppCompatButton@830022527720" for button object and everytime for my imageview i get "imageView: CircleImageView@830022434304" for my imageview object, As I said, I'm not really sure if that's the case, bottom line is, selected image is not being set!